# how to unbind checkbox List Or Remove checkbox list item in c#.?

Tags: c#

this is my code i want to clear my checkbox list because every text change event i'm getting new data from db.

```
private void txt_search_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fill_check();
    }

private void fill_check()
    {
        src.fun_search = txt_search.Text;
        try
        {
            DataTable dt_pro_name = db.findproduct_name(src);
            src.fun_search = null;
            if (dt_pro_name.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                src.fun_search = dt_pro_name.Rows[0]["id"].ToString();

                DataTable ds = db.addcombo(src);
                if (ds.Rows.Count > 0)
                {


                    imei.DataSource = ds;
                    imei.ValueMember = "imei";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Please tell me whats wrong in my code

Comment: Please remove the extra spaces, it's ugly and unreadable.

Comment: Remove that `catch{}` block. It won't make your code run, it will only hide what's wrong and make it impossible to fix it. If your code throws, you'll never now it and your controls will never be updated. There are many ways this code can throw - `findproduct_name` itself may throw or it could return `null`. There may be no `"id"` field. `addcombo` itself could throw or return null

Comment: What is src.fun_search here? and as @PanagiotisKanavos suggested  you won't see any errors because of try-catch so put a debugger there or remove them temporarily for debugging purpose.

Comment: try catch is just for control my exception